# Cannot find how to decease white space above top bar menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

@ 38VFR.COM there is a huge space between out search bar and top bar menu. Looked elsewhere and the solutions there didn't work or I am not finding the right attribute in the inspector to change. I am new to CSS/HTML/Wordpress.

I have tried altering the padding around the search bar to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow SE.

Comment: It would help you greatly to include [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem, because then we can answer you better.

Comment: ok...sorry about that

Comment: .site-header-top-main,
.boxed-layout #header-navigation-area .wrapper {
 padding: 0 30px;
}

.site-header-main {
 padding: 28px 30px;
}

.custom-logo {
 margin: 7px auto;
}

.site-title,
.site-description {
 margin: 0;
}

.custom-header-content {
 padding: 112px 30px;
}

Answer (score 0):

I make a habit of including `body { margin: 0; }` in my CSS styles and it seems to do the trick. If that doesn't work for you, please include a snippet of your CSS/HTML code so we can see what might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The space is created by the following entry in /wp-content/themes/catch-inspire/style.css

```
.site-header-main {
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 42px 30px;
}
```

Reduce the "42px" to maybe "5px"

If that does not work, then you could change this HTML tag:

```
<div class="site-header-main">
```

to:

```
<div class="site-header-main" style="padding-bottom: 0px">
```

Comment: Make sure to refresh the page with ctrl+F5 (in Windows browsers). It works for me when I make this edit via the console. If it still does not work, look at the more harsh change in HTML which I included in my answer.

Comment: It might not be: CSS files are often cached. You could also force it as follows: look for `style.css?ver=4.9.7` in the HTML file and change the version number to something else (does not matter what).